# Extract the assignment of from this expression with sonarQube

Tags: javascript, sonarqube

when I launch a sonar control I find myself with a smells code for the following function:

```
const changeMedia = (value: any, step: any) => {
    step.definition?.steps
      .filter((obj: any) => obj.media.includes(value))
      .map((item: any) => {
       if (value === 'EMAIL') {
         return (item.media = 'LETTER');
       } else if (value === 'LETTER') {
         return (item.media = 'EMAIL');
       }
         return item;
      });
    };
```

I get the following sonar alert:

> Extract the assignment of "item.media" from this expression.

What would be the solution to avoid this sonar message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const changeMedia = (value, step) => {
    step.definition?.steps
        .filter((obj) => obj.media.includes(value))
        .map((item) => {
            if (value === 'EMAIL') {
                item.media = 'LETTER'
                return item; // returning item instead of (item.media = 'LETTER')
            } else if (value === 'LETTER') {
                item.media = 'EMAIL'
                return item;
            }
            return item;
        });
};
```